# Retrieve text from clicked element

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

```
<div class="forInfo">
<div style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">17:00:00</div><br>
<div style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:large">zumba</div>
<div style="display:none" class="opis"> Ime instruktorja: ime Opis:opis</div>
<div style="text-align:center">ime</div>
</div>
```

This is the html code. I use the div with "opis" class just for storing text.

```
 $(".forInfo").click(function(){alert($(".opis",this).text)});
```

I have written this function in jquery, so that whenever I click on the div with class "forInfo" I get an alert with the text in the element with class "opis". However this does not work,I get the text function written in my aler.

Answer (score 4):

`text` is a method, not a property. See the [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
 $(".forInfo").click(function(){alert($(".opis",this).text())});
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/DFBph/)